# The Weil pairing on a generalized elliptic curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, moduli-spaces

Now I'm trying the section 6 (and 3.20) of chapter IV of Deligne-Rapoport's "Les schemas de module de courbes elliptiques".
I can't understand what $e_n$ (of 6.5.(d)) is.
It seems to be the Weil pairing.
So my question is:

> Let $n$ a natural number, $S$ a scheme on which $n$ is invertible, and $C/S$ a generalized elliptic curve, whose each geometric fibre is smooth or the Neron $m$-gon for $m | n$.
> Then how can I define the Weil pairing on $C^\text{sm}[n]$?

Here is what I have tried.

First, if $C/S$ is smooth, then trivially we have the Weil pairing.
And so it defines $\mathscr{M}_n^\circ[1/n] \to \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$.
($\mathscr{M}_n$ is the stack classifying the generalized elliptic curves with the level $n$-structures.
And $\mathscr{M}_n^\circ$ is the smooth part.
And $\zeta_n$ is the primitive $n$-th root of unity.)
The authors say that by the definition of normailziation, this induces $\mathscr{M}_n \to \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$.
(I can't understand it, because $\mathscr{M}_n$ is the normalization of $\mathscr{M}_n^\circ[1/n] \to \mathscr{M}_1$.)

And even if we get $\mathscr{M}_n \to \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$, this defines the Weil pairing only for generalized elliptic curves whose each fibre is smooth or $n$-gon.

Comment: $e_n$ is explained in IV.3.21, isn't it? Moreover, at least if $n>5$, ${\mathcal M}_n[1/n]$ is the normalization of ${\mathcal M}_n^0[1/n]$ (and this is what you need, since $n$ is invertible in $S$ by hypothesis in 6.5).

Comment: @Nulhomologous In 3.21, they define the Weil pairing only for $\mathscr{M}_m$, for $n|m$.
I want to define it for a generalized elliptic curves whose fibres are smooth or $m$-gon, for various $m|n$.

Comment: But they show this parings for various $m\mid n$ are compatible with each other with respect to the natural morphisms, isn't it?

Comment: @Nulhomologous Where is it? I can't find it.